# Looking to convert repetitive values to 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a report where I need all the data based on highest hierarchy.
I have got the results but one column values are repetitive because its coming from the Parent Group level data source and I cannot get it on lower hierarchy level.

Here's my table:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Kannan. I tried your solution and it works perfect!

Comment: But as Siyual mentioned you might require to provide Order by clause correctly to get the correct record as top row. But for sample i provided Group_Id as order by but since it is varchar you can identify better attribute for this...

Answer (score 0):

you can use Row_Number and provide values only for 1 as below:

```
Select *, 
       Case 
           When Row_Number() over(partition by Parent_Group_Id order by Group_Id) = 1 
               then Numbers 
               else 0 
       end YourOuputColumn
from yourtable
```

Comment: They aren't ordering by `Numbers`, they want it ordered by `Group_ID`.  But I also assume this is going to be an issue if they have more than 10 numbers in the group, since this will be using string sorting.

Comment: Thank you Siyual.